# Leveraging Borel-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ are measurable sets in the same probabiilty space such that $P(A_k)=P(B_k)$ for all $k$.  If you can show that $P(A_k \text{ i.o.})=1$ (for example, the $A_k$'s are independent and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_k)=\infty$) then is it necessarily true that $P(B_k \text{ i.o.})=1$?  (Obviously if I used Borel-Cantelli for the $A_k$'s, I am assuming that the $B_k$'s are not necessarily independent.)  I don't think this is so, but I can't come up with a counterexample yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big point is this: we have no information about how the $A_k$ correlate with each other or how the $B_k$ correlate with each other.  So, we can build a scenario like this:

Suppose we have a fair coin, which we flip over and over again.

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_k$ be the event that the $k$th flip yields heads; let $B_k$ be the event that the *first* flip yields heads.

Then $P(A_k)=P(B_k)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $k$, and $P(A_k\text{ i.o.})=1$, but 
$$
P(B_k\text{ i.o})=P(\text{first flip gives heads})=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Of course.  Bad question.  Slightly better question: are there other standard ways of proving $P(B_k \text{ i.o.})=1$ other than Borel-Cantelli (that is, in the absence of independence of the $B_k$'s)?

Comment: There are VERY few bad questions, I assure you!

For the rest: slightly more general is the [Kolmogorov 0-1 law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law); it says that if you have a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and a _tail event_ for the sequence - that is, an event that is independent of any finite initial sequence of the random variables - then that event must have probability 0 or 1. To get more general is difficult - it really depends on the nature of the relationship between your variables.

Comment: @HowardF. I can see this question as a good True/False question in an exam. Not a bad question indeed

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am familiar with the Kolmogorov 0-1 Law, but it still requires independence which is not available in the problem I'm thinking about.  After doing some more homework, I found the following post, which addresses more of the generalization that I had in mind: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134117/dependence-and-second-borel-cantelli-lemma](Dependence and second Borel-Cantelli lemma).