# How can I prove this result of the BC lemma?

Tags: probability

**Corollory 4**

If $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(A_n) = \infty$ and
 $$
 \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\underline{\lim}} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nP(A_i\cap A_j)}{\big(\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)\big)^2} = 1,
 $$
 then $P\Big(\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\overline{\lim}}A_n\Big) = 1$.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134117/dependence-and-second-borel-cantelli-lemma/2024050#2024050) post, I am looking at Theorem 5 which states:

**Theorem 5**
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) = \infty$ and if the $A_n$'s are negatively correlated in the sense that for ever $i,j \in \{1,2,...\}$ such that $i\neq j$,

$P(A_i \cap A_j) \leq P(A_i)P(A_j)$, then

$P\Big(\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\overline{\lim}}A_n\Big) = 1$.

**Proof**

By Corollary 4 it suffices to show that
$$
\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\underline{\lim}} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nP(A_i\cap A_j)}{\big(\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)\big)^2} \leq 1.
$$

**The above statement is what I am having trouble with. Why is it that because of Corollary 4, all you need to show is that inequality? What does that inequality mean in words?**

I'm even more confused because I am also looking at another proof which uses:

$$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k) \geq \frac{\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k)\bigg)^2}{\sum_{k,j=1}^n P(A_k\cap A_j)}$$

are these the same things?

This is the full proof of the second post I am looking at and I don't understand why they are both saying the same things:

**can someone please show me how to adjust the proof for when C=1**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a quick thought. Consider the discrete-time Markov chain with the state space $\{ 0,1,2,\dots\}$. Then consider the event $A_n= \{\mbox{ the chain returns to 0 in n transitions}\}$. Let $P(A_n)=p^{(n)}_{00}$. Then the condition you have mentioned at the beginning of your post $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(A_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty p^{(n)}_{00}= \infty$ means that the state $0$ is recurrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why is it that because of Corollary 4, all you need to show is that inequality?

Because $\liminf\frac{\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)}{(\sum P(A_i))^2}\ge1$ is rather obvious. To see this, note that $(\sum P(A_i))^2=(E\sum1_{A_i})^2\le E(\sum1_{A_i})^2=\sum P(A_i\cap A_j)$, where we used [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form).

2. Can someone please show me how to adjust the proof for when $C=1$?

Our goal is to show that $P(A_n~i.o)\ge1$, i.e., $P(\cap_{n\ge1}\cup_{k\ge n}A_k)=1$.

Now if we write $B_n=\cup_{k\ge n}A_k$, then it will be enough to show  $P(B_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Fix $n$. Next let us lower bound $P(B_n)$. Observe that for any $N>n$, we have that
$$P(B_n)=P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k)\ge P(\cup_{k=n}^N A_k)$$
and by Chung-Erdos Inequality we have
$$P(\cup_{k=n}^N A_k)\ge\frac{(\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i))^2}{\sum_{n\le i,j\le N}P(A_i\cap A_j)}.$$
As $P(A_i\cap A_j)\le P(A_i)P(A_j)$ for any $i\neq j$, it follows that
$${\sum_{n\le i,j\le N}P(A_i\cap A_j)}\le\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)+\sum_{n\le i\neq j\le N}P(A_i)P(A_j)\le\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)+(\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i))^2.$$
This implies that
$$\frac{(\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i))^2}{\sum_{n\le i,j\le N}P(A_i\cap A_j)}\ge\frac{{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}{1+{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}.$$
Putting everything together, we can conclude that for any $N>n$, it holds that
$$P(B_n)\ge\frac{{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}{1+{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}.$$
From our assumption we know $\sum_{i=n}^\infty P(A_i)=\infty$. So when $N\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac{{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}{1+{\sum_{n\le i\le N}P(A_i)}}\rightarrow 1$. Therefore $P(B_n)\ge1$ and thus $P(B_n)=1$.