# Does $o_p(1/n)$ mean when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have an $a.s.$ convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

If I have two functions (actually estimators), say $A_n(x)$ and $B_n(x)$, and I can prove $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |A_n(x)-B_n(x)|\leq o_p(1/n)$, can I conclude
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|A_n(x)-B_n(x)|=0 \; \; \; a.s.
\end{eqnarray*}
like that? If I can't, is there any way or lemma to prove something like this (strong conistency)? I have tried GC lemma, but it did not work, because my estimators are not step function. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What does the $p$ in $o_p$ signify?

Comment: @GregMartin $p$ as in probability, roughly speaking, $o_p$ is similar to the usual little-$o$, but it is for random variable, so if an rv $X_n=o_p(1/n)$, then the rv will converge in probability to $0$ at the rate of $1/n$

Comment: Are you asking if $\forall x, [\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |A_n(x)-B_n(x)|=0 \; \; \; a.s.]$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon ah sorry, i forgot to put $\sup$ there, i edited my question, thank you so much, ok, so, can I conclude the almost surely-ness?

Comment: You're essentially asking if the following implication holds:
$$[na_n \xrightarrow{P}0] \implies [a_n \xrightarrow{a.s}0]$$
Consider [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201695/almost-sure-convergence-of-textpoisson-frac-1n-to-0) with the hypothesis that the $X_n$ be indepedent. For any sequence of real numbers $u_n$ that goes to $0$ (e.g. $u_n=\frac 1n$), one can prove that $X_n=o_P(\frac 1n)$. However, as proved in the question, $X_n$ does not converge a.s. So you should not expect the implication to hold.

Comment: @GabrielRomon i see, then I have to look for another way to solve it, ok, thank you so much